# how to add functionality of removing node/element joint js

Tags: backbone.js, jointjs

I want to implement a functionality in which when I click on joint.js node extended by backbone view a div should appear around this element which will contain cross button and arrow button. 
When clicked on cross the node should be removed from paper of joint js when clicked on arrow user should be able to draw arrow. when click on other part of paper that div around element should disappear.
I am following this link http://jointjs.com/tutorial/html-elements.
what is the best approach of implementing this functionality as my own approach of hiding and showing divs around element is not working.

Comment: The example in the url that you gave works amazingly for delete. So are you having problem with arrow option? On a side note: I bet you are looking for something like [Halo from RappidJS](http://jointjs.com/rappid/docs/ui/halo).

Comment: It'll be better for us to help you out if you provide your implementation and tell us what went wrong.